# Length Converter from one unit to other - HTML

Tags: html

I was trying to write a Lenght Converter but I got a problem.
Every time I enter a value, the value is converted in miles and never in the other lenght.

For example if I write "2" in the first Feet input, the solution will be converted in Miles, which is the last output.

This happen for every Feet input I have in the code

Here the code and thank you for the help

Converter

```
<title>Converter</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

### Feet to measurement

```
    <p>
      <label>Feet</label>
      <input id="inputFeet" type="number" placeholder="Feet" oninput="LengthConverter(this.value)" onchange="LengthConverter(this.value)">
    </p>
    <p>Meters: <span id="outputMeters"></span></p>
    <script>
    function LengthConverter(valNum) {
      document.getElementById("outputMeters").innerHTML=valNum/3.2808;
    }
    </script>

    <p>
        <label>Feet</label>
        <input id="inputFeet" type="number" placeholder="Feet" oninput="LengthConverter(this.value)" onchange="LengthConverter(this.value)">
    </p>
    <p>Inches: <span id="outputInches"></span></p>

    <script>
    function LengthConverter(valNum) {
      document.getElementById("outputInches").innerHTML=valNum*12;
    }
    </script>

    <p>
        <label>Feet</label>
        <input id="inputFeet" type="number" placeholder="Feet" oninput="LengthConverter(this.value)" onchange="LengthConverter(this.value)">
    </p>
    <p>cm: <span id="outputcm"></span></p>

    <script>
    function LengthConverter(valNum) {
      document.getElementById("outputcm").innerHTML=valNum/0.032808;
    }
    </script>

    <p>
      <label>Feet</label>
      <input id="inputFeet" type="number" placeholder="Feet" oninput="LengthConverter(this.value)" onchange="LengthConverter(this.value)">
    </p>
    <p>Yards: <span id="outputYards"></span></p>

    <script>
    function LengthConverter(valNum) {
      document.getElementById("outputYards").innerHTML=valNum*0.33333;
    }
    </script>

    <p>
      <label>Feet</label>
      <input id="inputFeet" type="number" placeholder="Feet" oninput="LengthConverter(this.value)" onchange="LengthConverter(this.value)">
    </p>
    <p>Kilometers: <span id="outputKilometers"></span></p>

    <script>
    function LengthConverter(valNum) {
      document.getElementById("outputKilometers").innerHTML=valNum/3280.8;
    }
    </script>

    <p>
      <label>Feet</label>
      <input id="inputFeet" type="number" placeholder="Feet" oninput="LengthConverter(this.value)" onchange="LengthConverter(this.value)">
    </p>
    <p>Miles: <span id="outputMiles"></span></p>

    <script>
    function LengthConverter(valNum) {
      document.getElementById("outputMiles").innerHTML=valNum*0.00018939;
    }
    </script>

<h2> Meters to measurement </h2>
```

Comment: All your functions have the same name and your input fields have the same id, change them.

Comment: @Toto is right name your functions like toMeter, toInch, toMıles, etc. If you name them all same it will get the last function probably and always convert to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Your codes really do need some cleanup. Id's and function names should be unique.
2) Put all your scripts inside one script tag.

Hope this helps you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Converter</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
   <script>
    function LengthConverter(valNum) {
      document.getElementById("outputMeters").innerHTML=valNum/3.2808;
    }
     function inchConverter(valNum) {
      document.getElementById("outputInches").innerHTML=valNum*12;
    }
      function cmConverter(valNum) {
      document.getElementById("outputcm").innerHTML=valNum/0.032808;
    }
     function yardsConverter(valNum) {
      document.getElementById("outputYards").innerHTML=valNum*0.33333;
    }
     function kilometerConverter(valNum) {
      document.getElementById("outputKilometers").innerHTML=valNum/3280.8;
    }
     function feetConverter(valNum) {
      document.getElementById("outputMiles").innerHTML=valNum*0.00018939;
    }
    </script>
<body>
  <p>
      <label>Feet</label>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Feet" oninput="LengthConverter(this.value)" onchange="LengthConverter(this.value)">
    </p>
    <p>Meters: <span id="outputMeters"></span></p>
 

    <p>
        <label>Feet</label>
        <input  type="number" placeholder="Feet" oninput="inchConverter(this.value)" onchange="inchConverter(this.value)">
    </p>
    <p>Inches: <span id="outputInches"></span></p>
    <p>
        <label>Feet</label>
        <input  type="number" placeholder="Feet" oninput="cmConverter(this.value)" onchange="cmConverter(this.value)">
    </p>
    <p>cm: <span id="outputcm"></span></p>

    <p>
      <label>Feet</label>
      <input  type="number" placeholder="Feet" oninput="yardsConverter(this.value)" onchange="yardsConverter(this.value)">
    </p>
    <p>Yards: <span id="outputYards"></span></p>
    <p>
      <label>Feet</label>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Feet" oninput="kilometerConverter(this.value)" onchange="kilometerConverter(this.value)">
    </p>
    <p>Kilometers: <span id="outputKilometers"></span></p>
    <p>
      <label>Feet</label>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Feet" oninput="feetConverter(this.value)" onchange="feetConverter(this.value)">
    </p>
    <p>Miles: <span id="outputMiles"></span></p>
<h2> Meters to measurement </h2>

</body>
</html>
```